# FlatList issue when state changes [React Native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a data entry app that will handles a lot of data. Currently, i'm using `flatlist` to display the user entered data. But when user enters data continuously the apps performance is dropping drastically. Previously I've the same issue but i was using react-native-paper inbuilt datatable. So for rectifying that issue i used flatlist but the same issue is still exist here. When the state updates continously the whole performance is dropping. I've seen many issues related to the performance issue in reactnative flatlist. Is there any way to overcome this issue .

this is the code that i've using

```
const Item = ({ count,digit,countsum }) => (
  <View style={styles.itemcontainer}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{digit}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{count}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{countsum}</Text>
      </View>
  </View>
);

const renderItem = ({ item }) => ( console.log(item),
  <Item count={item.count} digit={item.digit} countsum={item.countsum} />
);

const Componentinput = React.memo(({data,setListData,scrollref}) => {
  const countRef = React.useRef();
  const digitRef = React.useRef();
  const values = React.useRef({ digit: '', count: '' });

  const onSubmitPress = async () => {
    const { digit, count } = values.current;
    const digitError = numberValidator(digit)
    const countError = numberValidator(count)
    const usertoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@userToken")
    if (digitError || countError) {
      alert('error occured')
      return
    }else if(digit.length < 3 || digit.length > 3){
      alert('enter 3 digit')
      return
    }
    let date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    setListData([...data, {digit, count, countsum:'', created_at:date}])
    axios
    .post(
      constants.BASE_URL+'savedata',
      { 
        digit: digit,
        count:count,
        created_at:date,
        token: usertoken
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    )
    .then(scrollref.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true}))
    .then(countRef.current.clear())
    .then(digitRef.current.clear())
    .then(values.current = {digit: '', count: ''},digitRef.current.focus())
    .then(response => { console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // setLoading(false)
      showMessage({
        message: "Error Occured",
        description: "Oops!! Please try again",
        type: "danger",
        color: "#fff",
        icon: "danger",
        floating: true,
      });
    });

  }
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.fixedform}>
      <View style={styles.textinputViewleft}>
          <NumberInput
            style={styles.textinput}
            ref={digitRef}
            label="Digit"
              autoCorrect={false}
              autoCompleteType="off"
              defaultValue=""
              clearTextOnFocus={true}
               onChangeText={(text) => {
              values.current.digit = text;
              if (text.length === 3) {
                countRef.current.focus();
              }
            }}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            maxLength={3}
            minLength={3}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textinputView}>
          <NumberInput
            style={styles.textinput}
            ref={countRef}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              values.current.count = text;
            }}
            label="Count"
            keyboardType="numeric"
            maxLength={3}
          />
        </View>
      <View style={styles.textinputView}>
          <Button style={styles.buttonView} mode="contained" onPress={onSubmitPress} >Submit</Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
});

const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [listdata, setListData] = useState([])
  const scrollViewRef = useRef();
  const ITEM_HEIGHT = 200;
  const getItemLayout = useCallback(
    (data, index)=>({
      length: ITEM_HEIGHT,
      offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index,
      index,
    }),
  );
  

  return (
    <Background>
      <Header style={styles.headermargin}></Header>
      <View style={styles.datatable}>
      <ScrollView
              ref={scrollViewRef}
              style={{ marginBottom: 70 }}
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
              }>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={listdata}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.created_at}
                maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
                getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <Componentinput 
        data={listdata} 
        setListData={setListData} 
        scrollref={scrollViewRef} 
      />
    </Background>
  )
}

export default React.memo(Dashboard)
```

Comment: I think `Flatlist` inside the `Scrollview` is a big no-no, do you really need to put it inside?

Comment: @Konstantin I need a fixed input box that's why I done like this